# Question on Sharepoint Web Analytics Web Part

Tags: search

This is a question about the Web Part 'Web Analytics Web Part'.  It has a view called 'Most Frequent Search Center Queries'.

When you use this you get a list of search terms most frequently searched for, and these terms are actually links.  They point to the root of the web app, i.e. http://test.com/results.aspx?test=abc.

In order to change this URL do I have to create a Search Center site?  Should this new site be a subsite to the site the search results statistics are based on?  The reason I want to change this URL is because I don't have results.aspx (or OSSResults.aspx - what was originally there) in the root of the app.  I have this page inside '_layouts' folder.  While I can change search settings, I cannot change where the Web Analytics Web Part term/links point to.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a "it depends" answer, since there are two different ways to look at it. You can create an enterprise search center as a stand-alone site collection, where you use this template:

[image]

... or you create an subsite with this template:

[image]

As you notice, there is no difference on these two templates, and whatever fits your needs you use. If you already have divided content in different site collections such as intranet.test.com, collaboration.test.com, document-center.site.com I think it would be a great idea to add the enterprise search center as an entity of its own in a site collection. But if you have only one site collection on your intranet, I'd use the subsite enterprise site collection.

Whatever fits your needs will decide which architectural steps you take. When it's created, make sure to update your search service application's search center URL to the actual search center, and all of your site collection search center URL's as well.